# Unable to publish the sharePoint designer 2013 workflow getting "Unexpected error on server while associating the worklow"

Tags: designer-workflow

I have reusable workflow in sharepoint 2013. It is created in SPD 2013. This workflow is designed to assign tasks to the groups and various approval levels. It seems looks like big. I have been publishing this workflow many times earlier and is working fine. Just I made some customization in my workflow last week. After that I'm unable to publish it. I'm getting the following error.

"**Unexpected error on server while associating the worklow**"

I increased the "UserDefinedWorkflowMaximumComplexity" of my SharePoint application. Workflow has around 20000. Also resetted the IIS. But everything has failed.

Please help!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked the SharePoint Logs. If we know the exact error in the Logs then the solution would be  easy..

Comment: Yes, we have checked. but it looks the logs have not enough error information related to this issue. Anyways we will check again and get back to you soon.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the  [SharePoint designer 2013 error Unexpected error on server associating the workflow](https://sharepoint-specialist.nu/sharepoint-designer-2013-error-unexpected-error-on-server-associating-the-workflow-235eaa801f7b) try the following:

1) Delete all folders in the following directory in local:
C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\SharePoint Designer\ProxyAssemblyCache\
2) Delete the files in all folders in this directory in local:
C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WebsiteCache\ don’t delete the folders, just delete the contents of the folders

If the issue is is not fixed still, try to Uninstall and install  SharePoint Designer 2013 again